# OpenGL Uniform Buffer std14 layout, normal on windows, error on macos

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple test program to test Uniform Buffer, it runs normally on windows, but it runs wrong on macos.

on windows
[show 36 quads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfoQe.png)
on macos
[show 5 quads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0HhE.png)

Uniform Buffer layout in shader

```
struct Instance {
    vec4 offset;  // offset 0
    vec4 color;  // offset 16
    float a;    // offset 32
    float b;    // offset 36
    float c;    // offset 40
};

layout (std140) uniform InstanceBlock {
    Instance instances[36];
};
```

C++ struct

```
struct Instance {
  std::array<float, 4> offset;
  std::array<float, 4> color;
        
  float a;
  float b;
  float c;
  float padding;
};
std::vector<Instance> instance;
for (int i =0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int j =0; j < 6; j++) {
        std::array<float, 4> color = {
        rand() / (float)RAND_MAX,
        rand() / (float)RAND_MAX,
        rand() / (float)RAND_MAX,
        1.0f
      };
      std::array<float, 4> of = {0, 0, 0, 0};
      instance.push_back(Instance{of, color, (float)i, (float)j, 1.0f});
    }
}
```

my code is error or a driver error?

Comment: Would [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781434/opengl-uniform-buffer-std140-layout) about `std140` layout answer your issue? The issue most likely comes from your `padding` field that I suspect is implementation dependent from the answer to the other question

Comment: Did not find the answer I wanted in the above paper. Because of model compatibility issues, Vertex Texture Fetch cannot be used in program.